# C# Unify Duplicated Methods different parameter types

Tags: c#, generics, methods

I Had to duplicate this method (made by another person) but I wanna know if there is a way to unify it,

this one receives an `IList<ViewModelA>`,
I need to pass to it an `IList<ViewModelB>`

with different properties, but the ones used in the method are in both are the same like `fatherId` or `Items`

I wanna know if there is a way to unify those methods with inheritance or interface or something else.

```
private IList<ViewModelA> TrasnformToTree(IEnumerable<ViewModelA> source)
    {
        var modelGroups = source.GroupBy(i => i.fatherId);

        var roots = modelGroups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key.HasValue == false).ToList();

        if (roots.Count > 0)
        {
            var dict = modelGroups.Where(g => g.Key.HasValue)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key.Value, g => g.ToList());

            for (int i = 0; i < roots.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(roots[i].Id))
                {
                    roots[i].Items = dict[roots[i].Id];
                    for (int j = 0; j < roots[i].Items.Count; j++)
                        AddChildren(roots[j].Items[j], dict);
                }
                else
                {
                    roots[i].Items = new List<ViewModelA>();
                }
            }
        }

        return roots;
    }
```

Comment: like: `IList<T> TrasnformToTree<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) where T : ISomeInterface`  and ISomeInterface needs to define the needed properties like `fatherId ` and `Items`

Comment: but it will not break in the line:  roots[i].Items = new List<ViewModelA>(); can I use T here too?

Comment: I posted a more complete and more or less tested example as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work for the code i'm seeing:

```
    private interface ISomeInterface<T>
    {
        int Id { get; set; }
        int? fatherId { get; set; }
        List<T> Items { get; set; }
    }

    private IList<T> TrasnformToTree<T>(IEnumerable<T> source) where T : ISomeInterface<T>
    {
        var modelGroups = source.GroupBy(i => i.fatherId);

        var roots = modelGroups.FirstOrDefault(g => g.Key.HasValue == false).ToList();

        if (roots.Count > 0)
        {
            var dict = modelGroups.Where(g => g.Key.HasValue)
                .ToDictionary(g => g.Key.Value, g => g.ToList());

            for (int i = 0; i < roots.Count; i++)
            {
                if (dict.ContainsKey(roots[i].Id))
                {
                    roots[i].Items = dict[roots[i].Id];
                    for (int j = 0; j < roots[i].Items.Count; j++)
                        AddChildren(roots[j].Items[j], dict);
                }
                else
                {
                    roots[i].Items = new List<T>();
                }
            }
        }

        return roots;
    }
```

Comment: could you explain may be why this answer solves the problem and what the thought behind the code is? it would grately improve the quality of your answer.